# javascript calculator and simulator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for good solutions to make calculation with javascript, for example: 100+5%= total.

```
$.fn.fonkTopla = function() {
var toplam = 0;
this.each(function() {
   var deger = fonkDeger($(this).val());
   toplam += deger;
});
return toplam;
};


function fonkDeger(veri) {
    return (veri != '') ? parseInt(veri) : 0;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name^="fiyat"]').bind('keyup', function() {
   $('#toplam').html( $('input[name^="fiyat"]').fonkTopla());
});
});
```

I am able now to calculate but still the total amount not resultung correctly, Anyone know why?

```
function euroConverter(){
document.converter.dollar.value = document.converter.euro.value * 0.04
document.converter.pound.value = (document.converter.dollar.value * 0.23 ) + 0
document.converter.yen.value = (document.converter.euro.value+document.converter.dollar.value+document.converter.pound.value  )
}
```

Here i did add .toFixed(2) , is fixed but still the total amount does not results correctly !

```
        function xConverter(){
document.getElementById("f40").value = (document.getElementById("f22").value * 0.04).toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("f41").value = (document.getElementById("f40").value * 0.23).toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("f23").value =  (document.getElementById("f22").value +  document.getElementById("f40").value + document.getElementById("f41").value )
document.getElementById("f70").value = (document.getElementById("f23").value + 1).toFixed(2)
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to refine it to ask specifically what you are trying to do, and what you have already tried, and what isn't working. For example, it's unclear what type of math you're trying to support, or what "100 + 5%" even means. Asking for "good solutions" is not a clear question.

Comment: The last time I checked, 100 + 5% made no sense mathematically.

Comment: the majority of this question seems to be about how to write a jquery plugin. calculating 105% in JS is a matter of `num * 1.05`. if the number is a string, `(Number.parseFloat(s) || 0) * 1.05`.

Comment: Hi Andy, What I am trying to do just input number field <input type="text" make copy to input field called total there should be the amount +5%= total , to make more clear is form system for money transfer donations.

Comment: @Thankyou Could you write me a complete example please?

Comment: @FZs The link is not working! , Thank you

Comment: @xxh I think there will, i did it but the % is not working with all my trying.

Comment: @yamen I provided a complete example below

Comment: @Thankyou Many many thanks my friend , there this link with working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1tbx479r/1/
My appreciation :-)

Comment: @yamen there is a link to a working example embedded at the end of my post. keeping code pastes on StackOverflow is preferred because off-site resources can be deleted and then link is dead. This is sometimes called “link rot” and is like plaque on the teeth of community message boards. Please do your part in flossing and brushing ^_^

Comment: @Thankyou I will remove this link later, I have other question, now all works will amount 100+4%= 104 , I want to know if there way to add 23% on this 4% number ? So the result will be 104,92

Comment: @Thank you , I did it but the total fields does not work :https://jsfiddle.net/283vtmoa/4/

Answer (score 0):

If we want to build something like this -

[image: tax calculator]

I would recommend something like this -

```js
$.fn.applyTax = function ({ tax = 0, input = "", output = "" }) {

  function calculateTax (s) {
    const n = Number.parseFloat(s) || 0
    return (n * (1 + tax)).toFixed(2)
  }

  return this.each(function(_, f) {
    $(f[input]).keyup(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      f[output].value = calculateTax(e.target.value)
    })
  })
}
```

Or forms should look something like this -

```html
<form id="myform">
  <p>Applies 5% tax</p>
  <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" /> =
  <output name="result">0.00</output>
</form>

<form id="myform2">
  <p>Applies 7.5% tax</p>
  <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" /> =
  <output name="result">0.00</output>
</form>
```

And you can use it like this -

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document.forms.myform).applyTax({
    tax: 0.05, 
    input: "amount",
    output: "result"
  })
  
  $(document.forms.myform2).applyTax({
    tax: 0.075, 
    input: "amount",
    output: "result"
  })
})
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser

```js
$.fn.applyTax = function ({ tax = 0, input = "", output = "" }) {

  function calculateTax (s) {
    const n = Number.parseFloat(s) || 0
    return (n * (1 + tax)).toFixed(2)
  }

  return this.each(function(_, f) {
    $(f[input]).keyup(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      f[output].value = calculateTax(e.target.value)
    })
  })
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document.forms.myform).applyTax({
    tax: 0.05, 
    input: "amount",
    output: "result"
  })
  
  $(document.forms.myform2).applyTax({
    tax: 0.075, 
    input: "amount",
    output: "result"
  })
});
```

```css
form {
border: 1px solid gold;
margin: 0 0 1rem;
padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <p>Applies 5% tax</p>
  <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" /> =
  <output name="result">0.00</output>
</form>

<form id="myform2">
  <p>Applies 7.5% tax</p>
  <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" /> =
  <output name="result">0.00</output>
</form>
```

Comment: I have a new update , could assist?, Thank you in advance.